# lodash Type Error has no function findKey()

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I am new to node.js-lodash. Currently I want to use `findKey()`-function of this library. Unfortunately, I get a type error. What went wrong?

```
var objCol = {
    'objA' : { 'myattrA' : 'myval1', 'myattrB' : 'myval2' }, 
    'objB' : { 'myattrA' : 'myval3', 'myattrB' : 'myval4' }
};
var obj = _.findKey(objCol, {'myattrA' : 'myval3'});
console.log(obj);
```

The corresponding error message in Eclipse Enide is:

> MessageBuilder : ERROR DETECTED IN event handler[39m [TypeError:
>
> Object function (obj) { if (obj instanceof _) return obj;
>
> if (!(this instanceof _)) return new _(obj);
>
> this._wrapped = obj;   } has no method 'findKey'] TypeError: Object 
>   function (obj) {
>
> if (obj instanceof _) return obj;
>
> if (!(this instanceof _)) return new _(obj);
>
> this._wrapped = obj;   } has no method 'findKey'

Comment: sure that you have lodash in `_` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was that OP forgot to load library to `_` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kirill, you were right, I forgot this line at the beginning:

```
var _ = require('./../node_modules/lodash');
```